# Row count on a SQL Server 2008 table to identify duplicates

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, row-number

I have records which can have multiple addresses associated with them, I normalized all of these into a table so I can see every address belonging to a record and identify duplicates (based on address line 1).

What I am trying to identify is a record that has the same address twice.  I accomplished this using a CTE and adding a row number for each occurrence of the address but I forgot am important part.  For every record, there is a Primary address, and this address, if it's a duplicate, should always have the lowest row number (RN).

Whats occasionally happens is that my primary address matches a non-primary address and the non-primary address gets RN = 1 and my primary gets RN > 1.

Since I want to inactivate these I'm looking for all address with RN > '1' that are not the primary address and I end up missing a bunch of results.  I added a column called 'PRIMARY_ADDR' but am not sure how to incorporate this field in the CTE.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ALL_Address_Table]
(
    [RECORD_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EXT_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADDR_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADDR_LINE_1] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ADDR_LINE_2] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [ADDR_ZIP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADDR_STATUS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PRIMARY_ADDR] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO ALL_Address_Table
    ([RECORD_ID], [EXT_ID], [ADDR_ID], [ADDR_LINE_1], [ADDR_LINE_2], [ADDR_ZIP], [ADDR_STATUS], [RN], [PRIMARY_ADDR])
VALUES
    (555678, '900120', '555678-100001', '123 MAIN ST','','58865','ACTIVE','','No'),
    (555678, '900125', '555678-100002', '123 MAIN ST','','58865','ACTIVE','','Yes'),
    (555678, '900145', '555678-100003', '123 MAIN ST','','58865','ACTIVE','','No'),
    (555678, '900115', '555678-100004', '500 W TRAIN ST','','58873','ACTIVE','','No')
;
```

**CTE**

```
WITH cte AS 
(
     SELECT 
         [RECORD_ID], [EXT_ID], [ADDR_ID], [ADDR_LINE_1], 
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY RECORD_ID, ADDR_Line_1 ORDER BY RECORD_ID) AS [rn]
     FROM ALL_Address_Table
)
update ALL_Address_Table
set RN = CTE.rn
from CTE
join ALL_Address_Table on CTE.RECORD_ID = ALL_Address_Table.RECORD_ID
where CTE.ADDR_ID = All_Address_Table.ADDR_ID

--This should not return a row with Primary_ADDR = 'Yes' but must be included in the count.
--I cannot just remove all the primary addresses or else I will miss the ones that have
--duplicates

select * from ALL_Address_Table where RN > '1'
```

**SQL FIDDLE**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52a0f/3

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just want to change it to `ORDER BY RECORD_ID, PRIMARY_ADDR DESC` so that the primary address gets the first RN slot? Not sure why RN and PRIMARY_ADDRESS are wide varchar columns.

I'm guessing this is throw-away code but your join condition might be better as:

```
inner join ALL_Address_Table
    on CTE.ADDR_ID = All_Address_Table.ADDR_ID
```

The RECORD_ID check looks to be redundant.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I was trying think past something as simple as changing the order.